# MS Access date sorting with date/time components combined in one text field

Tags: ms-access, datetime

I have a table in MSAccess, which is generated from another software. In that table, there a colmn with date/time elements. Here is a short content:

```
day,month,year,hour,minute 
1,3,2011,17,21
1,2,2011,18,33
```

The task is to build MSAccess SQL, which order rows by date/time formed with that data. Is there a way to do that without convert all to seconds?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Thank you HansUp. I agree with that correction in title. Hope that this will be useful for someone other too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do it without converting to a proper date/time format, but they will all be dog slow.  If it is at all possible to convert that field to a proper date/time field (or even add an extra field to hold the properly formatted date/time) then you should do that and be sure that the field is indexed.

If you are truly constrained and have to deal with the table as is, the most straightforward way to do it would be to write a function that translates that string to a date/time and sort by that function.

Here's a quick sample function:

```
Function ConvertDateTime(dt As String) As Date
Dim Flds As Variant
    Flds = Split(dt, ",")
    ConvertDateTime = DateSerial(Flds(2), Flds(1), Flds(0)) + _
                      TimeSerial(Flds(3), Flds(4), 0)
End Function
```

Then your query would include the following `Order By` clause:

```
ORDER BY ConvertDateTime([day,month,year,hour,minute])
```

**EDIT**: Your question is a bit ambiguous as currently asked.  If you actually have five separate columns, then the sorting is straightforward: `ORDER BY [Year], [Month], [Day], [Hour], [Minute]`
I assumed that was not the case or you would have easily figured that out on your own.

Comment: that do the work! Thank you mwolfe02. You are right, i was write in question - "that is column name" - which is wrong. Actualy this is a one column, and i already split values but, because i do not have enough knowledge on VB, that function - DateSerial - is my missink spot. Well, if values is in separate colmns - it's a trivial task. Thank you again :)